# How to sort an array in laravel sql based on a condition to check upto 2 digits

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

In my response i am getting

```
[
    {
        "id": 480,
        "HSN": 4808,
    },
    {
        "id": 575,
        "HSN": 5702,
    },
    {
        "id": 638,
        "HSN": 6301,
    },
    {
        "id": 765,
        "HSN": 7317,
    },
    {
        "id": 6626,
        "HSN": 47071000,
    },
    {
        "id": 6727,
        "HSN": 48081000,
    },
    {
        "id": 6728,
        "HSN": 48084010,
    }
]
```

But i want my response in sorted in a way , that it checks HSN (based on first 2 digits of HSN) and give me result like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 6626,
        "HSN": 47071000,
    },
    {
        "id": 480,
        "HSN": 4808,
    },
    {
        "id": 6727,
        "HSN": 48081000,
    },
    {
        "id": 6728,
        "HSN": 48084010,
    },
    {
        "id": 575,
        "HSN": 5702,
    },
    {
        "id": 638,
        "HSN": 6301,
    },
    {
        "id": 765,
        "HSN": 7317,
    }
]
```

i have tried sortBy ,sort methods but it seems not working for me , or i am doing this in wrong way .
help me to get it in correct way

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort

Comment: tried but getting error in response 
"Trying to get property 'HSN' of non-object"

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must read this documentation about [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

```
$data = [
    [
        "id" => 480,
        "HSN" => 4808,
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 575,
        "HSN"=> 5702,
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 638,
        "HSN"=> 6301,
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 765,
        "HSN"=> 7317,
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 6626,
        "HSN"=> 47071000,
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 6727,
        "HSN"=> 48081000,
    ],
    [
        "id"=> 6728,
        "HSN"=> 48084010,
    ]
];

usort($data, function($arr1, $arr2) {
    return strcmp($arr1['HSN'], $arr2['HSN']);
});

dd($data);
```

the explanation about usort and strcmp maybe you must read the documentation
to understand it more deeply.

[result sort by HSN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKKwy.png)